# What is the default event associated with map.pan() Arcgis api for javascript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

as title states I am looking for what happens when the map pans when using arcgis api for javascript. I understand the extent changes and a graphics.redraw occurs but if i associate these events to the zoom handler , I dont get the same results

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question...

the event is "pan"

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#event-pan

but you have also the events pan-start and pan-end

Comment: Well , yes I know that this event is fired, but also map.graphics.redraw is also called after pan-end. I have completed this application no longer need help. thanks.